# What makes this a bad answer?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer, answer-quality

This morning [I answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58852762/5495906),  addressing a user's code error and explained the ramifications of their syntax (backed up with further reading) and code/output examples. This afternoon I found out that it was not well received. I could understand if the score was 0, but why are downvotes warranted?

I know that nobody has to explain their vote with a comment, but I haven't been answering for long, and would like to better understand how to write good answers.

Is the issue that my source was Wikipedia? (It's a lot easier to search through than a draft standard for non [language-lawyer] questions, in my opinion.)

Is including an assembly intermediate as an explanation to a [c] question frowned upon without explaining both the compilation flag and ASM syntax for addressing?

Is my ratio of code-to-explanation off? Should I have left a comment asking for clarification of the user's usage of the integer format specifier? Talked about how loading an array into a register doesn't make much sense? I honestly don't know what I've done wrong!

Comment: Were the downvotes received during or after your several edits? Just wondering if someone downvoted it because they thought it duplicated one of the other answers in that question, before it was expanded upon further?

Comment: @404 Oh, that's a good question actually. I didn't notice any at the time, but I was focused on my 'agile' development of the answer. Am I right in thinking rep loss doesn't show up in the top right corner?

Comment: Also, I didn't see any other answers, they are all within a few minutes, and I don't see what makes the not-downvoted answer better than any other?

Comment: **"Am I right in thinking rep loss doesn't show up in the top right corner? "** Yes, it doesn't. Only positive values are shown there.

Comment: Rep loses show up in the Achievements list, but you don't get a notification.

Comment: In general, if you google the compiler error message and the first two hits already give a perfectly good explanation then posting an answer is not usually a great idea.

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that the answer is technically incorrect. The code with loop unrolling that you posted will not compile cleanly.

Indeed Wikipedia is a questionable source, it is much better to cite the standard (or a draft version of it). But that alone is no reason to down vote.

In this case it seems you only got half the truth - indeed we can't use `&` or pointer arithmetic on `register` qualified variables. But we can't use `[]` operator either because it is just "syntactic sugar" around pointer arithmetic. Please see [Do pointers support "array style indexing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747822/do-pointers-support-array-style-indexing).

If you had compiled the code as strict standard compilant `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`, it would tell you that the code isn't valid C.

> "error: ISO C forbids subscripting 'register' array" [-Wpedantic]

Apart from that the answer is OK, though it is worth mentioning that the `register` keyword is mostly obsolete today. It's a legacy keyword from the past when programmers were better than compilers at optimizing code.

Answer (score 6):

I think that when you've already said something is Undefined Behaviour, adding extensive disassembly showing what a particular compiler did, is usually superfluous and generally misleading.

I mean, if the behaviour is undefined, you shouldn't depend on it at all - it could change between compilers, or situations, or every time you build.

Having said that, the other two answers look fine to me, and they're at +3/-3 and 0/-2 at the time of writing. So, although your answer is improvable, I don't think those downvotes are proportionate.

Answer (score -13):

The multiple down votes across the question and all answers are atypical of normal Stack Overflow patterns and suggest some disgruntled bad actor using multiple accounts.

Comment: very unlikely that someone creates 3 sock puppet accounts with 125+ votes just to be able to massively downvote. I mean, this is possible, but 1) difficult 2) rare 3) why would this person downvote _all_ answers?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: There is a spread of down-votes across all the answers and the questions. For that to happen, either various people down-voted in complementary patterns (which is odd, usually there would be distinct asymmetry), or several people each down-voted across the board (which is also odd, rarely do people think all answers, especially ones that are substantially correct, and the question deserve down-voting), or one person down-voted across the board multiple times (which is also odd). As the latter requires only one actor, I think it has a significant probability.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: As to why, it could be the person with the currently deleted answer got pissed off and sought revenge. In any case, we should not have to guess; Stack Overflow administration would be able to see whether any one account down-voted everything and whether multiple accounts originating from the same IP address voted.

Comment: Or the person who deleted the answer is a downvoted victim, like the others. I should not reveal fraudulent patterns, but with a quick check on the person, they look clean and they're very unlikely to have socks that can - added - downvote.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Okay, so that person is not suspect and we do not know the motive. Nonetheless, the voting patterns require either improbable patterns among multiple people or a single improbable bad actor.

Comment: well, we could ask a CM, but in that case, it's probable that we would make fool of ourselves. I prefer keeping my credit for more plausible fraud cases.